# How can I navigate to lazy loaded module child routes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to lazy load module with child routes declared in it's routing configuration file,
The lazy module loaded successfully but I can't navigate to it's child routes.

I am using the technique as if it were a eagerly loaded module.
I declared path and inside it it's children.
Please see 'moduleB' routing file in the Plunker 
The link button is trying to navigate to the child route and load CmpC. but it fails.

Here is my root module routing decalration:

```
{ path: 'feature-b', loadChildren:'src/featureB/featureB.module#FeatureBModule' ,  pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Here is my lazy loaded module routing declaration.

```
export const moduleBRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component:CmpC , pathMatch: 'full',children:[
      {path: '' , pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'c', component:CmpB , pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]},

];

export const subRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(moduleBRoutes);
```

trying to navigate to : localhost:999/feature-b succeeded

trying to navigate to : localhost:999/feature-b/c failed

https://plnkr.co/edit/wFlJoDXRmAlMOswmwWFk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working DEMO** : **https://plnkr.co/edit/xAGjXqpmkLbCokvCt9qQ?p=info**

Removed unnecessary usage of

```
pathMatch:'full'
```

*Don't use it everywhere without any reason.*

And its now working as expected.

learn more about `pathMatch` here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html

Comment: It is working in your plunker but in my env. I get
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'feature-b/c'
any idea?

Comment: Please double check plunke. If it works in plunker, it will work in  your env.

Comment: How does this answer the question? He was asking about navigating to a path inside a lazy loaded module

Comment: This solved my problem (angular 6) as well; I was using `pathMatch: full` in my `app.routes` and removing it allowed my child module routes within a module to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, in my case no error appear but the view doesnt load, I can solved the problem by this way:

- This is my lazy module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ''
    },
    children: [
      { path: '', component: AdminComponent },
      { path: 'users', component: AdminUsersComponent },
      { path: 'games', component: AdminGamesComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

- This is my root module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: !environment.production })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now the routes:

- admin/
- admin/users
- admin/games

works perfectly

Comment: But what if you wanted `users` (instead of `admin/users`) to go straight to the `users` path in the lazy loaded module?

Comment: @CodyBugstein I am looking for something similar, Did you got any solution regarding this.

Comment: @CodyBugstein you can have something like `const routes: Routes = [{path: '', loadChildren: './test/test.module'},
{path: 'test2', component: Test2Component}];` in the root module. This way if you have this config `const routes: Routes = [{path: 'home', component: Test1Component}];
` in the lazy module(test), then  you can access this Test1Comp directly with  http://localhost:4200/home

Comment: @saikiran pls look at the above comment for your query